# Orientation of vector relative to other vector

Tags: euclidean-geometry, vectors

Given two directional vectors in 2D space, $\vec v=(v_x, v_y)$ and $\vec w=(w_x, w_y)$, what is the easiest way to calculate if $\vec w$ is orientated clockwise or counterclockwise relative to $\vec v$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computing

$$\det
\begin{pmatrix} v_x & v_y \\
w_x & w_y  \end{pmatrix}
$$
If it is positive, then $w$ is oriented counterclockwise relative to $v$, otherwise clockwise.

Comment: In case the OP is wondering where the heck that magic formula came from, there's a very simple geometric interpretation of the determinant as the z-component of the vector cross-product of v and w, and the condition for orientation can be figured out by the right-hand rule.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered

Answer (score 2):

Vector product would help. You can go a dimension up by writing $v=(v_x,v_y,0)$ and $w=(w_x,w_y,0)$. Than if $v \times w$ is positive(if $v \times w$=(0,0,a) where a>0), it means $w$ is orientated clockwise relative to $v$.